# Laravel - how to group data by key and save to array?

Tags: php, laravel

I have table attribute_values(id, value, attr_group_id).
I need to return the collection grouped by key attr_group_id.

in clear php using ORM RedBean i made:

```
$data = \DB::table('attribute_values')->get();
$attrs = [];
foreach ($data as $k => $v){
    $attrs [$v['attr_group_id']][$k] = $v['value'];
   }
return $attrs;
```

I need same using Laravel, after this one:

```
  $data = \DB::table('attribute_values')->get();
```

My table

```
  id    value     attr_group_id
   1     one          1
   2     two          1
   3     three        2
   4     four         2
   5     five         3
   6     six          3
```

And i need result

```
   Array(
[1] => Array 
    (
    [1] => one
    [2] => two
    )
[2] => Array 
    (
    [3] => three
    [4] => four
    )
[3] => Array 
    (
    [5] => five
    [6] => six
    )
  )
```

Comment: sorry, my pictures. 
my table : http://prntscr.com/o18o89 

and i need result: http://prntscr.com/o18oxp

Comment: try `$data = \DB::table('attribute_values')->groupBy('attr_group_id')->get();`

Comment: do you have Model For this if yes share the Model Name

Comment: no i havent. I do not want to create a separate model for this.

Comment: @ Sohel0415 it wont work because you are grouping the record in mysql query so the first record from each `attr_group_id` will be returened and rest of them will be skipped

Comment: please check my answer. it is described below. I made it for you. explained what the task was and how it was solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fetch all data, and map it with attribute id of every row will work,

```
$data = \DB::table('attribute_values')->get();
$attrs = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    // -> as it return std object
    $attrs[$value->attr_group_id][] = $value->value;
}
dd($attrs);
```

Comment: Please check my question. I made adjustments and added what I need: My table and need result.

Comment: try answer by @Martin Henriksen

Comment: since laravel has a collection so you don't need foreach

Comment: @Drakula Predator Larevel Version please

Comment: Ok if we will group by attr_group_id it won't give two results for the same attr_group_id but OP's result has two records per each attr_group_id. So @Martin Henriksen's data will fetch only three records and will skip remaining from each attr_group_id.

Comment: hey You need to look into it deeply we are not grouping the mysql query we are actually grouping the collection so groupby is added after `get` method so the collection will be grouped

Comment: @Manojkiran.A I upvoted Martin Henriksen's answer. Thanks, Learned something new. :)

Comment: I would argue this is not an optimal Laravel approach to the problem.

Comment: Please check my answer. it is described below. I made it for you. explained what the task was and how it was solved.

Answer (score 3):

Doing all this in raw `SQL` will be more efficient, `SQL` database are quite good at these operations. `SQL` has a group by function, since you are overwriting value, i just get it out with `max()` (this seems weird, that you overwrite the value, do you actually just want unique results?).

```
DB::table('attribute_values')
    ->select('attr_group_id', DB::raw('max(value)'))
    ->groupBy('attr_group_id')
    ->get();
```

**EDIT**
Since the scope has changed, you can utilize Laravels Collection methods, that is opreations on a Collection.

```
DB::table('attribute_values')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('attr_group_id')
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: Please check my question. I made adjustments and added what I need: My table and need result.

Comment: its the elegant way using colletion

Comment: Please check my answer. it is described below. I made it for you. explained what the task was and how it was solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **groupBy()** function of collection as:

```
$data = \DB::table('attribute_values')->get()->groupBy('attr_group_id');
```

It merges records with same attr_group_id under this field's value as making key of the collection.

Comment: Please check my question. I made adjustments and added what I need: My table and need result.

Comment: @SashaSan - This function creates a collection making attr_group_id attribute as a collection key. If you want to convert it into an array you can also use toArray() function of collection.

Answer (score 2):

**Friends, this is a ready task that I needed ! 
I did it myself and you helped me. If anyone interested can read.**

I'll explain to you why I needed this particular method. I am doing an online store with a clock and now there was a task to make filters and attributes for filters.
So there are three tables

```
attribute_groups table
```

[image]

```
attribute_products table
```

[image]

```
attribute_values
```

[image]

I need to display the Laravel widget on my .blade.php like as

```
{{ Widget::run('filter', 'tpl' => 'widgets.filter', 'filter' => null,]) }}
```

When i creating a new product in the admin panel. 
I must to save the product id and attribute_id in attribute_products, but there can be as many attributes as possible for one product. so, if I'll use this option

```
$data = \DB::table('attribute_values')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('attr_group_id')
            ->toArray();
```

I got result:

[image]

But! each new array starts with index 0. But I need an index that means its id. attr_group_id from  table attribute_value for saving into attribute_products. 
And after I see only one method for me.

```
$data = \DB::table('attribute_values')->get();
        $attrs = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $attrs[$value->attr_group_id][$value->id] = $value->value;
        }

        return $attrs;
```

and the result I was looking for

[image]

now you can see what's the difference and what was needed. Array index starts 1,2,3,4,5 and this index = attr_group_id. Unfortunately I could not initially ask the right question. thanks to all.

Comment: can you share the sql file wih some data. i will dig deeper into it and fulfill your requirement

Comment: bro ) I have already did what I needed .. I share my completed task.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Version **5.8**

So You need to Group the id
if You need in the Model Way I have created the Model as **AttributeValue**

```
$modelWay = \App\AttributeValue::get()
            ->groupBy('attr_group_id');
```

if You need in the DBWay I have created the table as attribute_values

```
$dbWay = \DB::table('attribute_values')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('attr_group_id');
```

Both Will give the Same Result

Comment: Please check my answer. it is described below. I made it for you. explained what the task was and how it was solved.